# Error in dredge(models) : could not find function "dredge"

Tags: function, mumin

MuMIn package is installed but when I try to run dredge dunction, it says
"Error in dredge(models) : could not find function "dredge".
How to solve this problem?

I have glm models with species richness as dependent variable and other environmental factors like land use and disutrbances as independent variables. My codes for this specific section are:
install.packages("MuMIn")
library(MuMIn)
models <- list(pmla1, pmla2, pmla3, pmla4, pmla5, pmla6, pmla7, pmla8, pmla9)
model.selection <- dredge(models)